# CakePHP remove email address from string

Tags: cakephp

Does anyone know of a CakePHP helper or existing helper function that can remove email addresses from text.

What I am trying to do is to hide the email address for job ads on a job board until the user has logged in, maybe it should be replaced by something like this: Login to show email

Anyone know how I can do this?

I am using cake 2.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this with CakePHP. PHP has a function for finding a string inside a string.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

You could find '@' inside your string or something like that. If the function returns false, no e - mail has been found.

Comment: i am nit sure you understand what I am trying to do. but what I was thinking was something like a regular expression to find an email address in the text and then replace that by something else. was hoping that such a function already exists, but will try to write my own function.

Comment: I understand but I think that you will need to write your own function too. This is just a help for it. :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use
https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/2.0/View/Helper/TextExtHelper.php#L44

```
$text = $this->TextExt->autoLinkEmails($text);
```

renaming it to removeEmails() and instead of using the replacement method for obfuscation you could write your own method here to replace your email with e.g. `*****`